# Suspicious warning from Resharper - should I change my code?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper, automated-refactoring

With the following code:

```
if (lombardiTrophy.Substring(1, 1).Equals('~'))
```

...I get, "*Suspicious comparison: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both 'string' and 'char'*"

Is there a better way to do this that wouldn't cause Resharper to raise its hackles?

Comment: `.Equals("~")` note the double quotes

Comment: single quote tries char, double quote forces string, if i remember correctly.

Comment: but it compiles fine, and a 1-character string is a char, right?

Comment: @ClayShannon No, a 1-character string is still a `string`, different type.

Comment: @ClayShannon it compiles fine because it compiles to `object.Equals(object)`, and, because the types are different, the method will always return false.  To reiterate, the expression `"A".Equals('A')` is false.  You've no doubt figured that out by now, but nobody else has explicitly called attention to that fact, which is the reason underlying ReSharper's warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should heed ReSharper's warning - Substring returns a string, and the single quote notation is a char, so you're comparing two different types.  You should compare a char to a char, which you can do like this:

```
if (lombardiTrophy[1].Equals('~'))
```

Of course you want to make sure that your string is at least two characters long.

Comment: @bugnuker The reason he's getting the error is that '~' is a char and Substring returns a string.  Since he just needs a character, he should use the Indexer ([]), which returns a char.  That way he's comparing char to char and not string to char.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 if (lombardiTrophy.Substring(1, 1).Contains("~"))
```

Note the double quotes for string comparison.